# DB trigger won't execute after SqlBulkCopy write to server new rows

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I'm trying to update `ssn` column after new row is inserted. Specify I need to set null to `ssn` column and set that encrypting value to another column. Is there any mistakes or what's wrong with my trigger?

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[MemberInsert]
ON [dbo].[Member]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN   
SET NOCOUNT ON;

OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SSN_Key
    DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE MyCer;

UPDATE Member
SET  [EncryptedSSN] = EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('SSN_Key'), inserted.SSN)
FROM inserted
INNER JOIN dbo.Member On inserted.MemberId = Member.MemberId

UPDATE Member
SET [SSN] = null 
FROM inserted
INNER JOIN dbo.Member On inserted.MemberId = Member.MemberId
END
```

Right now nothing happend with added rows. Also I have to add I insert new rows using `SqlBulkCopy`. Is it problem for trigger to catch event by this way?

Comment: @Jocelyn I've updated my question tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SqlBulkCopy doesn't check trigger by default, you must specify options: [SqlBulkCopyOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopyoptions(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var options = SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers | SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints;
using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, options, transaction))
{
    // ...Code...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't notice that there is such an option in `SqlBulkCopyOptions` enum!